# Read serial data from pc on android unity application with usb port

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, serial-port

I cant to read usb serial data on vr device.
The device works on android platform.

I tried `System.IO.Ports` namespace but unity says it can be only used in Windows platform.
How can I get usb serial data at android device?
Should I make some android aar plugin?

I can't find any references or examples in stackoverflow or google.
This is simple diagram that how my program works.

[PC Program] -> Send serial data 
--- connected with usb cable --- 
[Android application made by Unity] -> Receive serial data and do something with it.

Thank you.